# Ionic/Angular InvalidCharacterError

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a litte ionic (v.3.20.0) with cordova (v.8.0.0) app. After creating a component (ionic generate component ...) I get following error:

[image]

I#ve reverted my changes but nothing will solve the problem. The error dosnt occur with my changes. Has anybody seen this error before (in ionic or angular) and can tell me what the problem is an what I can do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the whitespace after 'buttom-clear-md-danger'<= this whitespace.

I saw that error before, but in my case was fired by a use of a special character like 'ñ' on one permutation like this {{ año }}

Comment: Hi, i dont use the buttom-clear-md-danger class. I think it will be used from ionic in the background. And also I dont use any special characters :(... Im dispairing...